# How to disable "true/false to !0/!1" minification in UglifyJS?

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

From my point of view there is one ambiguous thing in UglifyJS minification output. It replaces boolean primitives (true/false) with !0/!1. It looks more concisely but requires more operations and therefore more CPU time.

My question. Is there any way to disable this conversion?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You have to be on a really constrained system for this to make an actual difference...

Comment: Agree with @deceze, the bytes over the wire are probably prioritized over a negligible processing cost.

Comment: Thank you! But...

assume I have a such system where CPU time is more important than a few bytes. How can I achive my goal described above?

Comment: I guess you could create a small program that replaces !0 and !1 for the boolean values again... but I'm pretty sure that current JS interpreters can detect these constants and optimize the code during parsing, so I really think you should not worry about that

Comment: This question should be resolved in https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/1197#issuecomment-231378114 by now

Comment: Thanks ;) It was my question.